# Querying Relations with Parse Rest API

Tags: api, rest, curl, parse-platform

I am trying to get relation objects from a class. What I am doing looks something like this, but it is not working. Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

```
  curl -X GET \

   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxx" \

   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxx" \

   --data-urlencode 'where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type”:"Relation","className”:”Dog","objectId":"xkxJOVMcMv"},"key”:"dogs"}}' \

   https://api.parse.com/1/classes/owner
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your owner class has a relation field to Dog class and you want to get all the dogs someone owns via that relation. You should then to do this instead:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxx" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxx" \
--data-urlencode 'where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"owner","objectId":"<ownerid>"},"key":"dogs"}}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Dog
```

Comment: Sorry my code was missing a curly bracket so I edited it to be correct.

Comment: Basically there is an owner clas with I have a relation column that has a relation to the Dog class where there will be multiple dogs that belong to that owner.

Comment: Well the code above should give you all the dogs for that owner given that you replace <ownerid> with the owner objectId

Comment: Ah, I was missing a curly bracket at the end. Problem resolved! Thanks!